# Can we use a univariate regression as a dimensionality reduction method?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, dimensionality-reduction, univariate

Assume we have 500 predictors and one response. Can we perform a univariate regression on each pair Y-X and then select the predictors that have the highest R-squared and p<0.05? After that, we can use the selected predictors in multivariate combinations or step regression etc.

I have not found an answer why this is not advisable and I cannot mathematically prove why intuitively this sounds wrong.

I know that selecting the top-20, for example, predictors based on univariate R-squared does not guarantee that a multivariate model created by any combination of them will be better than a multivariate of the next 20 or the bottom 20.

Comment: Stepwise approaches have a lot of problems, which are explained well here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/121522

Answer (score 0):

The approach of fitting a separate **simple univariate linear regression model** for each predictor is not entirely satisfactory as each of the **500 regression equations (one for each predictor)** will ignore the other predictors in forming estimates for the **respective regression coefficients**.

If the predictors are **correlated** with each other this can lead to further problems.

Also , by fitting a **separate univariate linear regression model**, we may get a **small p-value**(i.e. the predictor is significant) for some of the predictor's coefficients. But , when a **multiple linear regression model** is fitted which includes many of the predictors , some of the **predictor coefficients** may have a **large p-value**(i.e. the predictor is insignificant).

Now , it can be the case that a **predictor's coefficient** is having a **large p-value** when present in a **multivariate regression model** ,while, in the case of   a **univariate linear regression model**  , was having a **smaller p-value**. Hence , this can also cause problems in interpreting the **important predictors**.

Techniques such as **mixed selection** , can help overcome the problem of **changing p-values** for **predictor coefficients**.